# Android AlarmManager Does Not Start Activity

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager

I have 2 instances of AlarmManager built into my source code - the 2nd of which is supposed to start an Activity at the time specified by the string: time. The textview displays the correct time for the string: time   however it never appears to start the 2nd AlarmManager's Activity (KillTimer.java) and I'm not sure why. I'm sure I've overlooked something simple but I'm not sure what it might be.

P.S.

I think it may have to do with the way I've implemented the time string - but I'm really not sure.

The time string should represent which can be multiplied by 1000 on the following line:

time != null ? 1000 : 0, pintent2);

However the source code never recognizes it and the Alarm never wakes the activity as it did before I added the string for time.

CODE SNIPPET: (Alarm which will not start using the value of the string: time)

```
 // Start 2nd service using AlarmManager


    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Rules.this, KillTimer.class);
    PendingIntent pintent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(Rules.this, 0, intent2,
            0);
    AlarmManager alarm2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            (time != null ? 1000 : 0), pintent2);
```

FULL SOURCE:

```
public class Rules extends Activity {
    private String password;
    private  PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
    String TIMELIMIT = "10";


TextView textSsid, textSpeed, textRssi, Time;
//Notification message ID
private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID=1337;

private int count=0;
private NotificationManager notifyMgr=null;
    public Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    public long mStartRX = 0;
    public long mStartTX = 0;
    public long txBytes;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rules);

    String NDEF_PREF = "prefs";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(NDEF_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    String name = prefs.getString("name", ""); 
    String code = prefs.getString("corename", "");

    String time = prefs.getString("time", "");
    String ssid = prefs.getString("restricted", "");
    Time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Time);
    Time.setText(time);


   Parse.initialize(this, "7gjqmUcoqu1IZPJSSxXLdE4L8efAugCXA7snLSH6", "5NckF83MUBumQ8L8zL7Akc4p07beMRnmvgCfhZdH");

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();


    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

textSsid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Ssid);
textSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Speed);
textRssi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rssi);
Time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Time);
Long.toString(mStartTX);
Long.toString(mStartRX);
Long.toString(txBytes);    
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());



mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED || mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
    alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
    alert.show();
} else {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
}

}

private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    TextView RX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RX);      TextView TX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TX);

        long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;
        RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
        long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()- mStartTX;
        TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);


        final Chronometer myChronometer = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        myChronometer.start();



        DisplayWifiState();
        this.registerReceiver(this.myWifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

    }

    private void registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver myWifiReceiver2,
            IntentFilter intentFilter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private BroadcastReceiver myWifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) arg1
                    .getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                DisplayWifiState();
            }
        }
    };

    public void DisplayWifiState() {

        ConnectivityManager myConnManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo myNetworkInfo = myConnManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo myWifiInfo = myWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

        if (myNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {

            textSsid.setText(myWifiInfo.getSSID());


            textSpeed.setText(String.valueOf(myWifiInfo.getLinkSpeed()) + " "
                    + WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS);
            textRssi.setText(String.valueOf(myWifiInfo.getRssi()));
        } else {
            textSsid.setText("---");

            textSpeed.setText("---");
            textRssi.setText("---");
        };

    // Start service using AlarmManager

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Rules.this, LMW.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(Rules.this, 0, intent,
                0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                7 * 1000, pintent);



        String NDEF_PREF = "prefs";
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(NDEF_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        String name = prefs.getString("name", ""); 
        String code = prefs.getString("corename", "");
        String time = prefs.getString("time", "");
        String ssid = prefs.getString("restricted", "");

        //String time = String.valueOf(time);




        // Start 2nd service using AlarmManager


        Intent intent2 = new Intent(Rules.this, KillTimer.class);
        PendingIntent pintent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(Rules.this, 0, intent2,
                0);
        AlarmManager alarm2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                (time != null ? 1000 : 0), pintent2);   




    // click listener for the button to start service
    Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), LMW.class));            
            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);



        }        

});

    // click listener for the button to stop service
    Button btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), LMW.class));
            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);

        }
    });





}};}
```

KILLTIMER.JAVA

```
public class KillTimer extends Activity {

    @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.killtimer);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "KillWifi Running!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      int networkId = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
      wifiManager.removeNetwork(networkId );
      wifiManager.saveConfiguration();

  }}
```

Broadcast Receiver Source:

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class StartKillTimerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        startActivity(context, KillTimer.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PendingIntent.getActivity
```

should be

```
PendingIntent.getService
```

No need to explain, I think you understand the difference here, it's kind of straight forward!

EDIT:

If you want to start an `Activity` with `AlarmManager` you should create a `BroadcastReceiver` and use the method `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`. Then inside your `Receiver` you should call `startActivity(context, KillTimer.class);`

Implementing the `Receiver`. You will also need to add the `Receiver` to your `Manifest`, such as: `<receiver android:name=".StartKillTimerReceiver" />`

```
public class StartKillTimerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startActivity(context, KillTimer.class);
    }
}
```

Remember that this `Receiver` has only one job to do, and that is to start your `KillTimer`. Now, in time it would be better to create a `Receiver` that can do multiple things. So if you wanted start different activities or whatever, you should also send data with the `Intent`.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not correct. I posted the contents of my KillTimer.java - if you see anything else - please let me know!

Comment: Well, you should certainly not use the getActivity, because you want to start a service, so getService is the method to use, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't want to start a service - I want to start an activity - the source of KillTimer is KillTimer extends Activity { not KillTimer extends Service { 

Are you still sure I should be using getService?

Comment: Well, since you wrote don't start Service, I'm not a mind reader. But now I can see that your KillTimer is an Activity.

Comment: Apologies good sir - that was a major typo on my end... I edited the title of the post from "AlarmManager Does Not Start Service" to "AlarmManager Does Not Start Activity"

Comment: Is there any way you can show me how this can be implemented?

Comment: Thanks! I added it as suggested - but now I'm getting: The method startActivity(Context, Class<KillTimer>) is undefined for the type StartKillTimerReceiver (I updated my source above - any suggestions?)

Comment: Also - it used to work in the manner I had previously - is that not an option? It was working at one point.

Comment: Thanks man. I forgot to register my Receiver on my manifest. Very stupid error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a broadcast Receiver triggering itself now and then..

1. You need all appropriate flags for an Intent before you start it as given below:

   ```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, Ring.class));
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    startActivity(i);
   ```
2. Declare permissions in Manifest.xml:

   ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
   ```

3.Ask for the permission (in the starting activity preferably)

3.1 Declare request code

```
public static int OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 3249;
```

3.2 Ask/check permission

```
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Display On Top permission")
                    .setMessage("Please grant the \"Display On Top\" permission.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                            startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
```

3.3 Permission callback

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            // You don't have permission
            checkPermission();
        } else {
            // Do as per your logic
        }

    }

}
```